# Как изменить цвет NavigationBar, StatusBar и TabBar в iOS7 без градиентов ?

Tags: ios, ios7

Пробовал изменить цвет интерфейса следующим образом

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
```

но вместо ярко-красного цвета получил бело-розовый, как это исправить без установки картинок на задний фон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple:

> Setting tintColor property by using
>   the appearance proxy APIs is not
>   supported in IOS 7

Попробуйте:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```

И учтите что `tintColor` берется от родителя.

[По поводу статус-бара.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @Алексей Алыбин, Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @AlexThumb, вы не спешите, ХК в своё время позаботится об этом - пришлёт для ТС нотификацию.

Answer (score 3):

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

> Use tintColor to tint bar button
> items. Use barTintColor to tint the
> bar background.